# Module missing from system.schema

Tags: 8

This is odd, I have a custom module I've had installed on a site for a while. I recently went to write an update hook for it and saw that Drush was not picking up the update I wrote.

After some investigation I see that there's no entry for the module in the `system.schema` collection in the `key_value` table. It appears this data is used to track which updates have been run for which modules.

Uninstalling and re-reinstalling the module restores the data.

Anyone know what could have caused this missing entry?

I have a bunch of hooks defined in the .module file and they all run fine. It's just that this record is missing.

Comment: What is your module machine name, and what did you name the update hook? And what file was it in?

Comment: Machine name is "pu_misc", the update hook is `pu_misc_update_8001()` and the file is `pu_misc.install`. After I manually added the entry for my module in the key_value table, it picked up the hook.